# JavaScript Variable in method modifying object's attribute?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a poker game in JavaScript. I thought the function that tested flushes worked perfectly until I displayed the hand AFTER the method ran. If there is a flush, this function is supposed to show the user's full hand, and then only the flush underneath it. Instead, it shows only the flush, and then the flush again underneath it:

```js
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var test = function() {
    var deck = new POKER.Deck(); //creates deck
    var hand = new POKER.Hand(); //creates hand
    //----------------TEST HAND UNTIL FLUSH-----------------
    while (hand.getValue() != POKER.HAND_TYPE.FLUSH) {
        deck.refreshDeck(); //refresh deck with new cards
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) { //populate hand
            hand.addCard(deck.dealCard());
        }

        console.log(hand.size() + " before"); //only for debugging. Prints "7 before"
        hand.testFlush();
        console.log(hand.size() + " after"); //only for debugging. Result unexpected

        if (hand.getValue() == POKER.HAND_TYPE.FLUSH) { //if hand has a flush
            for (var j = 0; j < hand.size(); j++) { //display full hand
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                var card = hand.getCardAtIndex(j);
                img.src = card.getImage();
                $("images").appendChild(img);
            }
            for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) { //display flush hand
                var img2 = document.createElement("img");
                var card2 = hand.getValueCardAtIndex(k);
                img2.src = card2.getImage();
                $("handImg").appendChild(img2);
            }
            break;
        } else {
            hand.empty();
        }
    }
  
};

window.onload = function() {
    test();
};
```

The second console.log statement prints out "4 after" until the testFlush method detects a flush, and the final result is "5 after".

testFlush method:

```js
POKER.Hand.prototype.testFlush = function() {
    //first, sort cards by rank so that the highest flush is 
    //taken if there are more than five cards of the same suit
    this.sortByRank();
    this.sortBySuit();
    var tempHand = this.cards; //modifiable version of this.cards
    var NUM_OF_TESTS = 3; //only 3 loops required to test for all possible flushes
    var LAST_CARD_INDEX = 4; //represents the fifth card, or index 4
    var MAX_CARDS = 5; //maximum cards possible in a hand (valueCards)

    for (var i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_TESTS; i++){
        //check if 1st and 5th cards are the same suit
        if(tempHand[0].getSuit() == tempHand[LAST_CARD_INDEX].getSuit()){
            this.value = POKER.HAND_TYPE.FLUSH;
            while(tempHand.length != MAX_CARDS){ //remove last card in tempHand until there are only five cards
                tempHand.pop();
            }
            this.valueCards = tempHand;
        }else{
            tempHand.splice(0,1); //removes first card from the temporary hand
        }
    }
};
```

All "hand.size()" does in the test function is "return this.cards.length". So what I don't understand is how the testFlush method could be altering the object attribute "this.cards" when it only alters the temporary variable tempHand.

Hand object:

```js
POKER.Hand = function(){
    this.cards = [];
    this.value; //integer that corresponds to the POKER.HAND_TYPE
    this.valueCards = []; //array of the five cards that corresponds only to this.value
};
```

Hand.size method:

```js
POKER.Hand.prototype.size = function() {
    return this.cards.length;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var tempHand = this.cards; //modifiable version of this.cards
```

Assigning an array or object to a variable does not make a copy of it. The variable is a reference to the same array, so `tempHand.pop()` modifies `this.cards` as well. You can make a copy of an array with `.slice()`:

```
var tempHand = this.cards.slice();
```

Comment: It might be worth stating that this applies to all objects. The line `var temp_var = original_var;` will only make a copy of a string or a number.

Comment: It's easier to just say that objects and arrays don't get copied, which is how I edited the answer.

Comment: That worked. Such a simple solution. So satisfying. Thank you!